# Auto refreshing php page

Tags: php, chat

I made this simple chat site for my website but I don't know how to make it auto refresh every time a message has been sent.

Site that sends and prints out all messages:

```
<form action="messages.php" method="POST">
    <input name="chat_box" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>


<?php
include "messages.txt";
?>
```

Site that sends text input to a text file:

```
<?php

$messages = $_POST["chat_box"];

$handler=fopen("messages.txt", 'a');
fwrite($handler,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"].":".$messages."<br>");
fclose($handler);

header("Location: chat_box.php");

?>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You probably don't want to *refresh the page*, but rather just update the "chat log" that's on the page.  There are a number of ways to do this, from web sockets to simply polling an AJAX resource at regular intervals.  There are also *countless* tutorials for this exact application.  Maybe a quick Google search for "simple php chat application" will help?

Comment: Thanks, will look that up

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

This is a `messages.php` :

```
<?php
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $sec = "10";
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="messages.php" method="POST">
        <input name="chat_box" /><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
    <?php
        include "messages.txt"; //Uncomment this to check the autorefresh
        echo "Auto refresh in 10 second!";

        $messages = $_POST["chat_box"];

        $handler=fopen("messages.txt", 'a');
        fwrite($handler,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"].":".$messages."<br>");
        fclose($handler);
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this help you out... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to get new messages, your best bet is probably to re-load the text file every 10 seconds. to do so replace the php in the bottom of your 1st code set with this:

```
<div id="messages"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function() {
     function functionToLoadFile(){
      jQuery.get('messages.txt', function(data) {
        $("#messages").html(data) 
      });
     }
setInterval(functionToLoadFile, 10000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's not working. Probably because i dont have jquery installed. I could use src="" but im just gonna keep it like this and refresh it manually